# Get Selected value of a Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a thousands of cells in an Excel worksheet which are ComboBoxes. The user will select one at random and populate it.

How do I get the selected ComboBox value? Is there a way to trigger a function (i.e. an event handler) when the ComboxBoxes has been selected?

Comment: do you mean you have 'validation' option in those cells?? not a real combobox which is a shape/form object...

Comment: @KazJaw this question really does need clarification :)  If OP has "thousands" of comboboxes, he'll need thousands of event handlers. Otherwise, if they're just validation option, a `Worksheet_Change` handler will do the trick.

Comment: @DavidZemens, after all... you are right :) So, I think there is already answer for the question in your comment and below (from @user20623626)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're dealing with Data Validation lists, you can use the Worksheet_Change event.  Right click on the sheet with the data validation and choose View Code.  Then type in this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox Target.Value

End Sub
```

If you're dealing with ActiveX comboboxes, it's a little more complicated.  You need to create a custom class module to hook up the events. First, create a class module named CComboEvent and put this code in it.

```
Public WithEvents Cbx As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub Cbx_Change()

    MsgBox Cbx.Value

End Sub
```

Next, create another class module named CComboEvents.  This will hold all of our CComboEvent instances and keep them in scope.  Put this code in CComboEvents.

```
Private mcolComboEvents As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolComboEvents = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mcolComboEvents = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(clsComboEvent As CComboEvent)

    mcolComboEvents.Add clsComboEvent, clsComboEvent.Cbx.Name

End Sub
```

Finally, create a standard module (not a class module).  You'll need code to put all of your comboboxes into the class modules.  You might put this in an Auto_Open procedure so it happens whenever the workbook is opened, but that's up to you.

You'll need a Public variable to hold an instance of CComboEvents. Making it Public will kepp it, and all of its children, in scope. You need them in scope so that the events are triggered. In the procedure, loop through all of the comboboxes, creating a new CComboEvent instance for each one, and adding that to CComboEvents.

```
Public gclsComboEvents As CComboEvents

Public Sub AddCombox()

    Dim oleo As OLEObject
    Dim clsComboEvent As CComboEvent

    Set gclsComboEvents = New CComboEvents

    For Each oleo In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(oleo.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
            Set clsComboEvent = New CComboEvent
            Set clsComboEvent.Cbx = oleo.Object
            gclsComboEvents.Add clsComboEvent
        End If
    Next oleo

End Sub
```

Now, whenever a combobox is changed, the event will fire and, in this example, a message box will show.

You can see an example at https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfj4kyzolfy03qe/ComboboxEvents.xlsm

Comment: I want to have a simple combobox without database or visual control, so without activex seems better for me?

Comment: You can use the combobox on the Forms section of the Developer tab. You assign a macro to it which runs every time it changes. It's a little more limited, but it's what I start with and I only move to ActiveX if there is a compelling reason.

Comment: Greetings to Nebraska, I have activex combobox now - looks nicer in design than without activex - and do not need the `class` and `event` code. `sub cbx_change() ... end sub` works, so why need the classes? To have several `change events`?

Comment: If you want a bunch of comboboxes to use the same code, you need the classes. If you have one or just a few, you can code each of their change events individually.

Comment: ok, With the class code(`event`, `events` and `standard module`) in the workbook/vba editor env, it gets hold of all comboboxes in all worksheets? Ah, I see it is for `sheet1`..

Answer (score 14):

You can use the below change event to which will trigger when the combobox value will change.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
'your code here
End Sub
```

Also you can get the selected value using below

```
ComboBox1.Value
```

Comment: Definitely this will work, but if OP really does have "thousands" of comboboxes on the worksheet, will need corresponding thousands of subroutines; 1 for each combobox.

Comment: I don't have thousands of comboboxes, just 1, and I am much obliged for the example.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to get the selected value from a ComboBox control is:

```
Private Sub myComboBox_Change()
  msgbox "You selected: " + myComboBox.SelText
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For ActiveX combo boxes, the .value option does not work directly in a procedure. The easiest solution I found was to use Workbook_Open to populate the value in the cell under my combo box (so it's hidden), then reference that in my code.

```
Private Sub ComboBoxName_Change()
  Range("C6") = ComboBoxName.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you'll be able to set the event handlers programmatically, using something like (pseudocode)

```
sub myhandler(eventsource)
  process(eventsource.value)
end sub

for each cell
  cell.setEventHandler(myHandler)
```

But i dont know the syntax for achieving this in VB/VBA, or if is even possible.