# How to Auto Filter a column using ComboBox value as Criteria in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have a spreadsheet that contains a list of Phone brands and Phone models (Phone brands are in column A, and Phone models are in column B)

I'm trying to do an ActiveX program that allows Users to select a Phone brand from ComboBox1 and Filter column A using the Value of the ComboBox1.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit 
Sub AdvFilter() 
    Dim lw As Long 
    Dim lr As Long 
    lw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    Range("A2:A" & lw).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("H1"), Unique:=True 
End Sub 

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() 
    Dim lr As Long 
    Dim Sel As String 
    lr = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    Sel = "H2:H" & lr 
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = Sel 
End Sub
```

I was able to populate comboBox1 with unique values from Column A, but I can't figure out how to filter it using the value of ComboBox1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have only got the list of phone brands so far from column A and written them (unique brands) to column H and put it as the list of values in Combobox. Now based on the value in combobox, you need to display the list of the phone models belonging to that brand in a column (say column I)

Step 1: Get the phone brand selected from combobox. Refer this example [VBA - Get Selected Value of Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535540/vba-get-selected-value-of-combobox)

Step 2: Get list of phone models under that phone brand. Let us say the phone brand is `phone_brand`

```
Sub getPhoneModels()
Dim iCol As Integer
iCol = 1
Dim phone_brand As String
phone_brand=getPhoneBrandFromComboBox()
For i = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If StrComp(.Cells(1, i), phone_brand) = 0 Then
            .Cells(9, iCol) = .Cells(1, i)
            iCol = iCol + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The above code will go through all the phone models in column B and write the ones with brand value as `phone_brand` in the column I (9)

`getPhoneBrandFromComboBox()` function is the function written in first step using the help given in link. This function returns the phone brand selected using the comboBox