# Refer to value selected in combo box with two columns on user form

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form with a combo box with two columns.  How do I refer to the values that are active in the combo box within VBA script on other parts of the user form (buttons, etc)?

Simply using `MyComboBox.Value` yields the value in the first column.  I can't figure out how to refer to the second column.

EDIT:  Based on advice below, I used this:

```
MyComboBox.List(MyComboBox.ListIndex, 1)
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535540/vba-get-selected-value-of-a-combobox

Comment: Who's `Me`? i.e. what code is trying to do that? Inside the form? A combobox with mutiple columns will only have *one* of these columns (the first one, which could be hidden) as the `Value`. That's completely by design.

Comment: I don't need the `Me`, you're right.  My problem is more how to refer to the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

The `Value` of a multi-column `ComboBox` will be the "key" value. You've presumably populated the dropdown from some list or array: *use that same source* to lookup the value corresponding to the selected key. Note the key/value wording: having the values in a `Dictionary` makes it very easy to retrieve the value of the second column.

Or, look it up from the control's `List` (which is essentially a copy of your items source), using the `ListIndex`, which gives you the index of the selected item in the source list.

You can have a `Property Get` procedure responsible for this lookup - then other parts of the code can easily consume it as needed.

```
Private Property Get SelectedItemDisplayText() As String
    SelectedItemDisplayText = MyComboBox.List(MyComboBox.ListIndex, 1)
End Property
```

Normally you only care for the selected "key" (/"ID"), not the "display value" though.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! is there a way to display one value and have the "key" value be the other column?  For example, could I display the user name after selection but have the user ID stored as the value?  Also would a listbox be better suited to what I'm doing?

Comment: The ID is always the leftmost column, but it can be hidden (tweak the `ColumnWidths` property, e.g. `0;100`). Whether a `ListBox` is more appropriate depends on what you're doing... and your problem description is rather slim.

Comment: Ah, I think I found a way to do it `MyComboBox.List(MyComboBox.ListIndex, 1)`

Comment: If you hide the ID column, you'll have the "display value" of the selected item in the box' `Text` property